# Wrong android onClickListener being fired when view is touched

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am having some trouble with the onClickListeners that I have added to two text views that are part of an accessibility bar within an app I am working on. When the app is on a tablet the listeners behave as expected and increase and decrease the text size properly, however when run on a phone only the increase size listener is called no matter which view is touched.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be most grateful, below is the code that is adding the two listeners.

```
            accLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    accLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView bigger = new TextView(this);
    bigger.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bigger);
    bigger.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenWidth/5, utils.dpToPx(60)));
    bigger.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             htmlLayout.increaseTextSize();

        }
    });

    TextView smaller = new TextView(this);
    smaller.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smaller);
    smaller.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenWidth/5, utils.dpToPx(60)));
    smaller.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              htmlLayout.decreaseTextSize();
        }
    });

    TextView invert = new TextView(this);
    invert.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.invert);
    invert.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenWidth/5, utils.dpToPx(60)));
    invert.setHeight(utils.dpToPx(60));
    invert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!HtmlLayout.INVERTED){

                 htmlLayout.invertColours();
                 HtmlLayout.INVERTED = true;
            } else {

                 htmlLayout.unInvertColours();
                 HtmlLayout.INVERTED = false;
            }

        }
    });     
    LinearLayout sliderContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    sliderContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider);
    sliderContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((screenWidth/5)*2, utils.dpToPx(60)));
    sliderContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    SeekBar brightness = new SeekBar(this);
    brightness.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int) (screenWidth * 0.4), utils.dpToPx(30)));
    brightness.setMax(100);
    brightness.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    brightness.setProgress((int) (0.7 * 100));
    brightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.screenBrightness = (float)(progress + 20) / 100.0f;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    sliderContainer.addView(brightness);

    accLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    accLayout.addView(bigger);
    accLayout.addView(smaller);
    accLayout.addView(invert);
    accLayout.addView(sliderContainer);
    mainContainer.addView(accLayout,2);
```

Comment: Try this one: in place of `TextView bigger = new TextView(this);`, put `TextView bigger = (TextView)finViewById(R.id.TextView1);` and in place of `TextView smaller = new TextView(this);` , put - >`TextView bigger = (TextView)finViewById(R.id.TextView1);`. This way you'll be sure to attache the listeners to the correct Views.

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly but I don't know if I'm missing something, the views do not exist until instantiated using `new TextView(this)`, as there are no XML layout files behind the app and everything is generated dynamically.

Comment: Can you show the code how you create the layout? Maybe the two TextViews overlap on the phone.

Comment: @Henry code for the whole layout added in edit

Comment: check the id for both the textviews.

Comment: check the id for both the textviews.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks correct. You could try changing the background for each view, assuming they are the same colour, to see exactly how they are being presented on the screen.

I don't have my IDE to hand to test it but I suspect they may not be laid out as you intend.

Comment: I have checked for overlapping and have swapped the invert and decrease locations in the bar, even when the decrease and increase are at opposite ends of the bar the both still increase the text size.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Switch the order in which you add them. Right now you add 'bigger' then 'smaller'. Let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: I switched the positions, it seems the problem is not with the `onClickListener()` as I have now managed to get it to hit the breakpoint and the correct listener is fired. The problem seems to be with the `getTextSize()` method on the `TextViews` within the htmlLayout